# Flask database models 1:M relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect two tables in Flask. SQLite gets the input from the first table ('User'), but when trying to get the input from the second one ('Feedback') I am getting this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: feedback.user_id

```
from fimekapp import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
   return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User (db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column (db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column (db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column (db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column (db.String(60), nullable=False)
    feedbacks = db.relationship ('Feedback', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
           return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

class Feedback(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    student = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    grade = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text())
    date_posted = db.Column (db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
           return f"User('{self.student}', '{self.grade}', {self.comment}')"
```

These are my routes:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_pw = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        new_user = User(username=form.user.data, email=form.email.data, password = hashed_pw)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Account created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Registration', form=form)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if new_user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(new_user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(new_user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('feedback'))
        else:
            flash('Unable to login! Check your email and password.', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

@app.route('/feedback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def feedback():
    form = FeedbackForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_feedback = Feedback(student=form.student.data, grade=form.grade.data, comment=form.komentar.data)
        db.session.add(new_feedback)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('OK!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('feedback.html', title='Feedback', form=form)
```

As you can see I am very new at this so please forgive me if I don't see something obvious.
Thanx!

Comment: Hey! I think you're implementing 1:1-- to implement 1:M relationship-- you should use db.relationship

Comment: I am using db.realtionship: `feedbacks = db.relationship ('Feedback', backref='author', lazy=True)`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What input are you supplying?

Comment: No problem.I use 2 FlaskForms with 3 routes. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Exactly what Cfreak has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
new_feedback = Feedback(student=form.student.data, grade=form.grade.data, comment=form.komentar.data)
        db.session.add(new_feedback)
        db.session.commit()
```

You'll either need to set `new_feedback.author` or pass `user_id` as a keyword to `Feedback`

It fails because you set the user_id column on Feedback as `nullable=False`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please? If I set variable new_feedback to new.feedback.author I get NOT NULL constraint failed: feedback.user_id. How do I pass user_id as a keyword to Feedback?

Comment: Got it! Fixed it with `author=current_user`Thanx Cfreak!! You got me thinking!

Comment: sorry I didn't see your replies sooner. Glad you got it figured out :)